# Is it possible to construct a Symfony path using only parameters?

Tags: php, symfony, drupal-8

I would like to reduce the number of repetitive code and give a canonical URL in my Drupal 8 application. Since the routing system is built on Symfony, I included it in the title.

I am constructing paths under routes in my mymodule.routing.yml file. I want to match a specified number of different strings in the first argument, and a slug which can be any string in the second argument. It looks like this:

```
entity.my_entity.canonical:
  path: '/{type}/{slug}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\namespace\PostController::show'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'perm'
    type: different|strings|that|can|match|
```

Now, when I try to access using for example `/match/some-slug` then it just says "Page not found".
If I something static to the path, for example `path: '/j/{type}/{slug}'`, then it works as expected when I open `/j/match/some-slug` in the browser.

My boss doesn't like any unnecessary characters in the URL though, so I would like to achieve this by using two parameters, like shown in the first example.

Comment: Make sure there isn't another path that could have conflict with it, because it's possible perfectly.

Comment: How could I find out? Would it be considered a conflict if another path has two parameters as well, or only if the parameters have the same name?

Comment: Use `php bin/console debug:router` to debug your defined routes, and checks the order also

Answer (score 1):

As Yonel mentioned in the comments you can use debug:router to check all your routes. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Try running `bin/console router:match "/match/blaaa"` and if you see some controller that isn't the one you want then you'll need to change the route. It shouldn't be the case though because you're getting a 404.

Here's my exact setup that works

routing.yml:

```
entity.my_entity.canonical:
  path: '/{type}/{slug}'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'MyBundle:Something:foo'
  requirements:
    type: different|strings|that|can|match|
```

Inside MyBundle\SomethingController:

```
public function fooAction($id)
{
  return new Response("bar");
}
```

Then going to http://localhost/match/fom shows the "bar" response.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found out now that it is not possible in Drupal 8. And for other Drupal people: the command to get a list of routes (with Drupal Console) is `drupal router:debug`

Answer (score 0):

I have read the documentation again (RTM), and found out that it is not possible in Drupal 8, while it is possible in Symfony.

> Note that the first item of the path must not be dynamic.

Source: [Structure of routes in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes)